# Trailing profit and stop loss exit immediately on purchase using Pine Script v5

Tags: pine-script

Pine Script v5

When testing a build on the TradingView strategy tester for a stop loss and a trailing profit, the code just exits on the buy straight away.

I have tried to change the *strategy.close* to a *strategy.exit*, but I just cannot identify what I am doing wrong.

Code:

```
//=======================================================================================================
//=================================== Trades Entry ======================================================
//=======================================================================================================

    //******************* Buy Position Long Trade *******************
if bb_long_entry_condition
    strategy.entry("EL", strategy.long, comment="EL")

current_order_buy_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

//=======================================================================================================
//==================================== Stop Loss ========================================================
//=======================================================================================================

    //******************* Configure stop loss to get the stop value (below) *******************
    // For the percentages 0.1 = 10%, 0.01 = 1%, 0.005 = .5%
long_stop_percentage = input.float(title="Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.001, defval=.01) * 0.01
long_stop_loss_price = current_order_buy_price * (1 - long_stop_percentage)


//=======================================================================================================
//====================================== Trailing Profit =================================================
//=======================================================================================================

    //******************* Configure trail stop multiplier to get the stop value (below) *******************
    // For the percentages 0.1 = 10% and 0.01 = 1%, 0.005 = .5%
long_trailing_percentage = input.float(title="Trailing Long Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.001, defval=.01) * 0.01
long_trailing_price = 0.0

    // This picks the highest value from the values specified within the brackets
long_previous_close_price = math.max(close[1], close[2], close[3])
long_trailing_price := long_previous_close_price * (1 - long_trailing_percentage)

//=======================================================================================================
//=================================== Exit Trades =======================================================
//=======================================================================================================
//---------------------- Exit Trade Position -----------------------------

if long_stop_loss_price < current_order_buy_price
    strategy.close("EL", comment="xSL", immediately = true)

if long_trailing_price < long_previous_close_price
    strategy.close("EL", comment="xTP", immediately = true)
```

I have tried changing to % for both the stop loss and the trailing percentage to make it (in theory) impossible for a exit straight away, but it just does.

I have tried using both the *strategy.exit* and *strategy.close* in the simple form.
*strategy.close* as above and the *strategy.exit* with *stop = long_stop_loss_price* (for stop loss) and *long_trailing_price* (for the trailing profit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `long_trailing_price` is always lower than `long_previous_close_price` since you are calculating `long_trailing_price` as `long_previous_close_price * (1 - long_trailing_percentage)`.

That means that the condition `if long_trailing_price < long_previous_close_price` is always `true` and the `strategy.close()` function will always be called immediately after entering.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that as well after posting... was looking and not seeing. Appreciate the help.